# How do I load a third-party PHP library in a module?

Tags: 7

Suppose I want to load facebook-php-sdk in my Drupal website, how can I load that class file in a custom module? I tried with the Libraries module, with different functions provided by that module, but everytime I fail.

Comment: You can also include custom libraries placing them in a directory, for example sites/all/libraries, and loading them through the template's .inc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same way in [Drupal for Facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fb) module and put these code in your custom module:

```
 $fb_lib_path = function_exists('libraries_get_path') ? libraries_get_path('facebook-php-sdk') : 'sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk';
 $fb_platform = $fb_lib_path . '/src/facebook.php';
 try {
     if (!class_exists('Facebook') && !@include($fb_platform)) {
      //show error
      return NULL;
     }
     $fb = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => $appId,
       'secret' => $secret,
       'cookie' => $cookie));
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {}
```

You can check the fb_api_init function of [Drupal for Facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fb) module for more detail.

Comment: I used same approach for a different library in drupal. In my case i need to use API class defined in /src/Api.php file. For me !(class_exists('Api')) is coming 1 i.e class is showing non-existed, though it exists. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

[Libraries API](https://drupal.org/project/libraries) is a module designed to take the burden of this from your shoulders. You probably have it already installed, as it is required by many other modules.

> The common denominator for all Drupal modules/profiles/themes that integrate with external libraries.
>
> This module introduces a common repository for libraries in sites/all/libraries resp. sites//libraries for contributed modules.

When you put library where it needs to be, simply use:

```
libraries_load($name);
```

> You can also attach library to renderable array like that:

```
$form['myelement']['#attached']['libraries_load'][] = array('libraryName');
```

More detailed documentation here: [Using Libraries API 2.x (as a module-developer)](https://drupal.org/node/1342238). That's the source of code snippets I pasted here .